# Leading dots with right indent tab in InDesign TOC

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I have a table of content that currently looks like this:

[image]

However, I am trying to add leading dots between the title and the corresponding page number. Here's what my **Table of Contents...** dialog looks like:

[image]

But I'm not sure where to define that leading dot. I tried adding a dot in the **Between Entry and Page Number** field but it didn't help. Any idea?

Update: On Scott's recommendation below, I tried adding the "dot" character to the Tabs dialog of the Paragraph Style option but it didn't yield any difference. This is what I did:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the leaders to the **tabs** Not in the TOC dialog, in the Style dialog.

[image]

Comment: I tried it but am not sure how to go about it. I added the dot in the Leader field for each of the 4 "arrow" buttons on top. But nothing is showing. I didn't enter anything in the X and Align On field as those are the fields I don't understand. Updated the question with a screenshot of my Tabs dialog.

Comment: You need to alter the `A Chapter Title` style based upon your screenshot.  The `x` field is the position of the tab from the left side. The `Align on` field is used if you want the tab to align text on a marker, like a dollar sign or decimal or something like that.

Comment: @AmitSchandillia Your style screenshot shows *no tabs* You can't have a leader if there's no tab to follow it. You need to add a tab on the right side. Take another look at my screenshot... see that right aligned tab in it??

Answer (score 2):

In the table of contents set-up, you've got ^y instead of ^t in the "Between Entry and Number" field. I don't know if this is your only problem, but the Indesign Reference Manual (updated as of June 15, 2015) suggests this.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott wrote, you need to change the Paragraph Style you set to the TOC entries. Since you find it difficult, [have a look to this step-by-step guide](https://redokun.com/blog/indesign-table-of-contents) (see the "Put dots between the entries and their page numbers" section)